# Destructuring array-of-objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, for example:

```
 myArray = [
    {id:1, Fname:'Parker',Lname:'Smith',email:'demo@gmail.com',phone:"1313",adress:"TEst"},
    {id:2, Fname:'Robet',Lname:'Leng',email:'demo@gmail.com',phone:"1313",adress:"TEst"},
    {id:3, Fname:'Asia',Lname:'Smith',email:'demo@gmail.com',phone:"1313",adress:"TEst"},
  ]
```

I want to Destructure it  into

```
DestructuringArray = [
    {id:1, Fname:'Parker',Lname:'Smith',email:'demo@gmail.com',phone:"1313"},
    {id:2, Fname:'Robet',Lname:'Leng',email:'demo@gmail.com',phone:"1313"},
    {id:3, Fname:'Asia',Lname:'Smith',email:'demo@gmail.com',phone:"1313"},
  ]
```

Comment: `myArray.forEach((obj) => delete obj.adress)`

Comment: that doesn't work, the accepted answer from that question doesn't work for this particular case but it there is another answer that solves the issue like this one 
`const DestructuringArray  = myArray.map(function(item) { delete item.adress; return item; });`